# Adding space between two divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have defined a section in HTML file with two divs next to one another as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to add space between two horizontal divs in the HTML file?

Comment: That HTML is malformed, each div should be closed. And they are nested divs, not next to one another.

Comment: Please provide more information about your html. This problem sounds can be addressed by css margin

Comment: Where is this second div take place? After the col-sm-4? Use margin css for the class, you want to add space after.

Comment: @Pete ... haha, extremely sorry ... I have now modified the example above :-)

Comment: Still need to know what grid system you are using - there may be inbuilt classes for what you want, also how much space do you want?

Comment: @Pete ... thank you for your kind support. I am still learning how to ask better questions at stackoverflow. By the way, I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your snippet it seems you are using bootstrap, if this is the case then you can add space between two horizontal divs in bootstrap as follow:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
```

where: col-ms-offset-{value}. add space (as specified) to the left of the div. and you should remember that the size of all divs including offsets, must sum to 12 in bootstrap grid system as the above example.

Comment: I'm not telling him to use bootstrap, my answer apply only if he is using bootstrap already @Rob

Comment: You're right. I hadn't noticed the bootstrap stuff.

Comment: @adnamuttaleb ... thank you, the proposed solution worked fine.

Comment: you are welcome  @engqureshi

Answer (score 1):

if you want to space two divs you can do the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-sm-4 {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions about the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the kind suggestions.